# Where can I find a single summary coverage number in Cobertura?

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I run Cobertura on my codebase and get coverage numbers by the class, line, and branch.

Besides this, I am looking for a single summary number which tells me the coverage for my whole codebase. That's not enough of course; the detailed reports are essential. But having a single number gives us a metric which we can continually improve.

I don't see such a number in the reports. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [sample report](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/sample/), the total metrics are reported in the "All Packages" row.

Comment: Thanks. The slightly confusing thing is it is in a header row where one does not expect to see data, rather than a summary row near the bottom. But yes, the info is there.

Comment: sample report link is broken

Comment: Here is a working sample report - http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/sample-maven-shared-io-report/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `format="summaryXml"` attribute for this

```
<target name="summary-coverage-report">
    <cobertura-report srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${coverage.summaryxml.dir}" format="summaryXml" />
</target>
```

See the example [here](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/blob/master/cobertura/examples/basic/build.xml).

Comment: example here link is broken